# Play Framework - JBoss Channel Exception

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, playframework

I'm starting with Play Framework and when I'm sending the following commands, it throws a exception.

```
# play
```

In Play Console:

```
[play-java] $ run
```

It throws:

```
org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /0.0.0.0:9000
at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$10.apply(NettyServer.scala:171)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$10.apply(NettyServer.scala:168)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
at play.core.server.NettyServer.<init>(NettyServer.scala:168)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:347)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:345)
at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$.mainDev(NettyServer.scala:344)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$.mainDevHttpMode(NettyServer.scala:340)
at play.core.server.NettyServer.mainDevHttpMode(NettyServer.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at play.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(PlayRun.scala:233)
at play.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(PlayRun.scala:91)
at scala.Function7$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function7.scala:35)
at scala.Function7$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function7.scala:34)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:366)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:290)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm trying using my local user, root user, changing ports (ie: `run 8080`), `start` instead of `run`, and it always throw the same exception.

By the way, port 9000 is not in use by another application.

Anyone has any clue?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and Play Framework 2.2.6.

Thanks.

Comment: I remember Play used to have some problems with skype randomly trying to use the port. First thing I thought of. Try switching it of completely. (Killing the service) and then doing this

Comment: I do not have Skype installed on my machine. But it's a clever thought, thanks!

Comment: What does `lsof -i:9000` return?

Comment: With a regular user it returns nothing, with root: `php5-fpm 2236     root    6u  IPv4  15028      0t0  TCP localhost:9000 (LISTEN)`. So I changed the port in console as root and it works. Apparently I have not changed the port as root, only with a regular user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that your port is being used by another process.

In a UNIX machine the command `lsof -i:9000` will give the processes that are using the port.

---

As you have noted correctly processes with `root` permissions can be hidden if you use the terminal not as `root`